# ext.net Toolbar position: fixed

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, position, ext.net

I want to fix a `<ext:Toolbar>` inside a Panel, to be always shown at  the top.
As i am not using Anchor-Layout, but a Table-Layout in my Panel i can't anchor the Toolbar.

When i added a ViewPort around the Panel, it does no more `autoscroll`

that's why i tried:

```
<ext:ToolBar runat="server" StyleSpec="position: fixed;">
   <Items>
      //some Buttons
   </Items>
</ext:ToolBar>
```

but that had no effect

for explanation:

I load some MVC-View to a table-like Border-Layout with

```
<ext:Panel Region="North" ID="TopBarPanel" />
<ext:Panel Region="West" ID="NavBarPanel" />
<ext:Panel Region="Center" ID="ContentPanel" />
```

After a little searching on docs.sencha.org I must admit I have not found anything like `window.constrain=true` to keep the toolbar locked inside the Panel's Viewport

Comment: I have read the question, then re-read, but have not understood where you need to place a Toolbar. Maybe, you need to put a Toolbar into a Panel's TopBar.

Comment: that is the point. but how can i make sure, that topBar will not be scrolled out of the frame?

Comment: Then a Toolbar should be out of a container with scrolling. As another approach you can try to organize a floating toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniil stated, ext.net simply does not allow this. instead moving the content into a wrapping container inside the center panel fixed the problem.

```
<ext:Panel Region="Center" ID="ContentPanelWrapper" runat="server">
   <Items>
      <ext:Toolbar runat="server" />
      <ext:Panel runat="server" ID="ContentPanel">
         <Items>
             //Content goes here
         </Items>
      </ext:Panel>
   </Items>
</ext:Panel>
```